# How to see what is using sndiod / audio devices

Tags: audio, openbsd, mpd

When running `mpc play`, after it previously running fine and then opening some browsers, which likely try to play sounds, I receive the following error:

`Failed to open "sndio output" [sndio]; Failed to open default sndio device`

I assume the browsers have taken over the default `sndio` device.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2):

To monitor connections to sndiod, it must be started it in the foreground with the "-dd" options.

Multiple programs may share the same device, but for privacy reason they must belong to the same user.

My guess is that mpd runs as user _mpd. This is the prefered setup when the audio hardware is dedicated to mpd, for instance on a headless media player. In this case, the _mpd user will try to get exclusive access to the device, which may be already in
use by browsers.

To run mpd concurently with other audio programs, you've to start it as your own user.